# Spring Boot cookie domain issue after enabling forward headers

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, cookies, session-cookies

In my Spring Boot app (w/ embedded Tomcat), I enabled forward headers by setting the `server.use-forward-headers` property to `true` in my `application.properties`.

Because of an issue with `X-Forwarded-Host` when doing this, discussed [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2603), I added the suggested [code snippet](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2603#issuecomment-228321172) to get it working. That all worked well, however I noticed that the domain on my cookies has changed.

Specifically, my `JSESSIONID` domain used to be either `example.com` or `abc.example.com`, if on a subdomain. After adding that code snippet, my `JESSIONID` domain is always `.example.com`.

I'm not quite sure why adding that code changed the cookies. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out that I have a custom Cookie Serializer for my `JSESSIONID` cookies that hasn't been working properly. For my custom Cookie Serializer, I copied the code snippet from https://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/guides/custom-cookie.html.

The `DomainNamePattern` was not matching before enabling forward headers, and so the cookie domain was `example.com`. After enabling forward headers (specifically `X-Forwarded-Host`), the domain now matched, causing the custom serializer to make the cookie domain `.example.com`.

In order to avoid potentially weird behavior for my users, or having to invalidate all user `JSESSIONID` cookies, I opted to comment out the domain name pattern matcher, and stick with `example.com` as the cookie domain for now.